# Can I ReRender the entire tree of a component?

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF application with several major components and a component tree under each.

On a certain event (Value change) I would like to reRender the entire component tree for one of those components.

For example: can I rerender components 1,2 and 3 in one shot here:

```
<h:panelgroup id="1">
 <h:panelgroup id="2">
  <h:panelgroup id="3">
  <h:panelgroup/>
 <h:panelgroup/>
<h:panelgroup/>

<h:commandButton rerender="1*"> <--- Made up code.
```

Is that possible?

Another Idea - Can I reRender with wildcards? (I.E - ReRender all components who's ID's begin or contain: "UpdateMe")

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can re render whole trees.

You can't use wildcards (afaik), but you can use expressions - for example

```
reRender="#{yourBean.yourRenderExpression}"
```

which can return comma-separated list (or a `Collection`) of elements to reRender.

Generally, you have to pass arguments that follow [`UIComponent.findComponent(..)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) algorithm.

Note that `<h:commandButton>` doesn't have a `rerender` attribute. It's either `<a4j:commandLink` and `reRender` (capitalized), or you should use `<f:ajax>` from jsf 2.